# Modify api response before sending to client

Tags: node.js, proxy

```
const express = require('express');
const  proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();


app.use( '/api', proxy({ target: 'https://swapi-graphql.netlify.com/.netlify/functions/index', changeOrigin: true })); 


app.listen(8080);
```

I have this proxy but I'd like to modify the response before sending it back to the client.
Right now it sends the response directly to the client when the request is made. Is there a way to do this? You can also suggest a better NPM package if this one is not suited for what I want.

Comment: `http-proxy-middleware` has options maybe you want to check that out, and how do you want to modify it, "Do you want to send derived response ??" https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options

Comment: @SarthakDwivedi I would just like to send the first item of the response for example. I checked the options but i find it hard to select which one i need , could you maybe help me with that

Comment: last week I had to do something similar when an api endpoint accepted only https, instead of using proxy, I setup a simple express api and used axios to send derived req data.